# including login form in base.html

Tags: python, django

I'm using `context_processors.py` to pass the login form to all of my views, then I can include it in all of my pages

here are my files

**context_processors.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


def include_login_form(request):
    login = AuthenticationForm()
    return {'login': login}
```

**base.html**

```
    <div class="well well-small" style="width: 220px">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <img src="{% static 'img/user.png' %}">
            <div id="btns">
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}"><button class="btn-danger">تسجيل الخروج</button></a>
            </div>
            {% else %}
        <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ login.as_p }}
            <div id="buttons" align="right">
    <button class ="btn btn-primary" type="submit">تسجيل الدخول</button><br><br>
                </div>
  </form>
                  <a href="{% url 'signup' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
          إنشاء حساب جديد</button></a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

But my login form is not working at all, It just reloads the page after pressing on submit 
 any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told the form where to submit to; your HTML `<form>` tag needs an `action` attribute with the URL of your login view.

Comment: I can only include HTML files in the action att, can't include the login URL from URLs.py, or maybe I miss understood, can you please show an example?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Of course you can put the URL there, why do you think you can't?

Comment: `action="{% url 'login' %}"` didn't work, `action='login` also didn't work , the default login form in Django have no `view`

Comment: And your answer gave me the idea of creating my own login view to work with and it worked , thank you